# C How do XOR between unsigned int pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, xor, unsigned

I have two unsigned int pointers with 32 bit and I want do an XOR operation between these unsigned pointers.

```
char* a = "01110011011100100110111101000011";
char* b = "10111001100011001010010110111101";
unsigned* au = (unsigned*) a;
unsigned* bu = (unsigned*) b;
unsigned* cu = a ^ b;
```

Error is:

```
 invalid operands to binary ^ (have ‘unsigned int *’ and ‘unsigned int *’)
```

Comment: What kind of operation are you trying to do? `a` and `b` point to strings containing sequences of `'0'` and `'1'` characters, not bits. Converting those pointers to `unsigned*` doesn't give you anything particularly meaningful, and could have undefined behavior. If you want to do an xor on strings of `'0`` and `'1'` characters, you'll have to write it yourself. If you meant `01110011011100100110111101000011` and `10111001100011001010010110111101` to be bit sequences, don't represent them as strings.

Comment: I have two strings <plain text> and <encoded text>, I converted these strings into binary and I put them into an array (char a and char b) to make an xor operationto find the decrypt key.

Comment: <plain text> and <encoded text>? You didn't say anything about that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have strings, not unsigned integers.  You'll need to convert them to unsigned integers before you can do bitwise operations on them:

```
char* a = "01110011011100100110111101000011";
char* b = "10111001100011001010010110111101";
unsigned au = strtoul(a, 0, 2);
unsigned bu = strtoul(b, 0, 2);
unsigned cu = a ^ b;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs to work a little harder to pull that off.

1. Iterate over the strings.
2. Pull the numbers from the digits.
3. Perform an XOR between the numbers.
4. Convert the number to a digit.
5. Add the resultant digit to the output.

---

```
char str1[] = "01110011011100100110111101000011";
char str2[] = "10111001100011001010010110111101";
char* p1 = str1;
char* p2 = str2;
for ( ; *p1 != '\0' && *p2 != '\0'; ++p1, ++p2 )
{
   unsigned int n1 = *p1 - '0';
   unsigned int n2 = *p2 - '0';
   unsigned int n = n1 ^ n2;
   char c = n + '0';

   // Now you can change either a or be to contain the output.
   *p1 = c;
}

// At this point, str1 should contain a string that looks like you performed an XOR between str1 and str2.
```